# Json.NET : Serialization with Square Brackets

Tags: c#, json.net

How can I have a **header** for my items like:

```
{"geometricShapes":[{"circle": "1","triangle": "2","square": "3"},{"circle": "1","triangle": "2","square": "3"}]}
```

My current result:

```
[
  {
    "circle": "1",
    "triangle": "2",
    "square": "3"
  },
  {
    "circle": "1",
    "triangle": "2",
    "square": "3"
  }
]
```

The method I used:

> Deserialize to add the elements to the model object then make a list with 2 copies of it (*geometricShapesList*)

```
            string jsonString = '{"circle": "1","triangle": "2","square": "3"}'
            Model.GeometricShapes geometricShapes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GeometricShapes>(jsonString);
            List<GeometricShapes> geometricShapesList = new List<GeometricShapes >();
            geometricShapesList.Add(geometricShapes);
            geometricShapesList.Add(geometricShapes);
            string jsonStringUpdated = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(geometricShapesList, Formatting.Indented);
            Console.WriteLine(jsonStringUpdated);
```

Comment: A "header" as you call it, outside of a {...} - is not valid JSON. Neither is the `geometricShapes:` without quotes. No decent JSON tool is going to help you produce invalid JSON. Would it be OK to have an object that *has* a property that is the list/array? *That* is trivial. Heck: `SerializeObject(new { geometricShapes = geometricShapesList })`

Comment: I guess you want your JSON to look like this: `{"geometricShapes":[{"circle":"1","triangle":"2","square":"3"},{"circle":"1","triangle":"2","square":"3"}]}`

Comment: @Luuk Exactly! Sorry for the typing error.

Comment: So I just add to to do `var newJson = new { geometricShapes = geometricShapesList};`, serialize `newJson` and print it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use classes to solve your problem. I suggest to you following solution. You can use [Json to C#](https://json2csharp.com/) to generate classes from json string.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string jsonString = "{\"circle\": \"1\",\"triangle\": \"2\",\"square\": \"3\"}";

            Root root = new Root();
            GeometricShape geometricShape = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GeometricShape>(jsonString);
            List<GeometricShape> geometricShapesList = new List<GeometricShape>();
            geometricShapesList.Add(geometricShape);
            geometricShapesList.Add(geometricShape);

            root.geometricShapes = geometricShapesList;

            string jsonStringUpdated = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, Formatting.Indented);
            Console.WriteLine(jsonStringUpdated);
        }

        public class GeometricShape
        {
            public string circle { get; set; }
            public string triangle { get; set; }
            public string square { get; set; }
        }

        public class Root
        {
            public List<GeometricShape> geometricShapes { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "geometricShapes": [
    {
      "circle": "1",
      "triangle": "2",
      "square": "3"
    },
    {
      "circle": "1",
      "triangle": "2",
      "square": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```